# python dictionary to sqlite insert

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

As I m reading about SQLLite3 and Python, I tried this simple dictionary to  DB approach. I have tried a few stackoverflow forums but now able to figure out how to get this data from dictionary to database and then print it. Code below:

```
import sqlite3

user_dir={}

#connect a built in function to connect or create db
conn=sqlite3.connect('phonebook.db')

#Create a cursor function which allows us to do sql operations
crsr=conn.cursor()

#Create a Table
#crsr.execute(""" Create Table phonebook(
#            f_name text,
#            phone text)
#            """)

def create_user():
    while True:
        rsp=input('Create new user: Y/N ?')
        if rsp=='y':
                f_name = input('Enter first name: ')
                #First name cannot be empty
                while (len(f_name)==0):
                   print('First name cannot be empty')
                   f_name = input('Enter first name: ')
                phone = input('Enter phone number: ')
                user_dir[f_name]=phone
                #crsr.execute("INSERT INTO phonebook VALUES (?,?)", [user_dir["f_name"], user_dir["phone"]])
                #crsr.executemany("INSERT INTO phonebook VALUES (?,?)", user_dir)
                columns = ', '.join(user_dir.keys())
                sql = "INSERT INTO phonebook VALUES (?,?)" % ('phonebook', columns)
                crsr.execute(sql, user_dir.values())

        if rsp=='n':
            break

    crsr.execute("SELECT * from phonebook")
    print(crsr.fetchall())
```

Errors are different for each commented out lines. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: do you need the `columns` list? If you want to just insert the `f_name` and `phone`, does this work? `sql = "INSERT INTO phonebook (f_name, phone) VALUES ('%s','%s')" % (f_name, phone)` works when I test it with your table schema.

Comment: ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type is the error I am getting. I tried it without the columns just like you have mentioned. I had to change this line as well crsr.execute(sql)

Comment: After making the change above now it works.